# Resigning and uploading ipa to app store

Tags: ios, iphone

We have an ipa file(that was signed with ad hoc distribution). We wish to upload this ipa to the app store. How can we do it? I mean resign the ipa and then use application loader to load it to the app store?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First off, you'll need a valid "Distribution" certificate, as opposed to a "Development" certificate. Once you obtain that cert and load it into Organizer, you need to adjust the Code Signing rules within your build settings. Building for release should make use of your distribution cert.

Once you've archived the ipa using these settings, you'll see an option to "Validate" within Organizer, which will automatically look for some common configuration issues, respond to these accordingly.

Finally, the App will have to be in the "Ready For Upload" state within iTunesConnect to even begin the upload process.

Just dive into it, the errors thrown at each step are rather intuitive and helpful.

Comment: That's great, its required for the App Store. Did you try the next steps yet? If something's not right the errors given are very descriptive, or worst case you can post them here and we'll all chime in.

Comment: Please read again my question. I have an already signed ipa which i simply want to resign.

Comment: similar at all to this? [http://www.modelmetrics.com/tomgersic/codesign-re-signing-an-ipa-between-apple-accounts/](http://www.modelmetrics.com/tomgersic/codesign-re-signing-an-ipa-between-apple-accounts/)

Comment: What is the correct workflow? We want to send a version to our testers (signed as ad hoc) and then to make sure that we upload that same exact version to apple (signed for app store). Is there a way to generate something that is not signed and then sign it each time with a different signature?

Answer (score 1):

I have had success in resigning IPAs with this open source IPA resigning app called, [iReSign](https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign).

I would recommend testing any resigned builds.